# Using a Rust macro to generate a function with variable parameters

Tags: rust, macros, macro-rules

I've created a Rust macro which expands to a function declaration.

```
macro_rules! build_fn
{
    ($name:tt) => {

        pub fn $name(&self) -> Result<i32, Box<dyn Error>>
        {
            // <implementation>
            
            Ok(0)
        }
    };
}
```

Is it possible to expand this so the macro can take variable parameters?

e.g.

```
($name:tt, /*$variable_args ? */) => {

        pub fn $name(&self, /*$variable_args ? */) -> Result<i32, Box<dyn Error>>
        {
            // ...
            
            Ok(0)
        }
    };
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3a27b399a9d3736975c7a5fbac6bfc81)

Comment: [Repetition](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/macros/repeat.html)?

Comment: Yes, I think I need something like this `$($arg:expr),*` .. but I can't quite get the syntax right. It makes me question if it's possible in this context but I confess that macros are certainly my weak point with Rust.

Comment: `$($arg:expr),*` covers expressions, you need names and types for the arguments. You can use something like `$($p:pat : $t:ty),* $(,)?` for full cover, but if that's at the end, better to  use `$($args:tt)*`.

Comment: I've made _some_ progress with this but it's still not right for multiple args. [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d798cc6a744b53af47dd8cf40fc3b115)

Answer (score 5):

Indeed, it's possible. You need to expand the parameters as `$field: $ty`:

```rust
use std::error::Error;

macro_rules! build_fn
{
    ($name:tt, $($v:ident: $t:ty),*) => {

        pub fn $name(&self, $($v: $t),*)
        {
            let args = [$($v,)*];
            println!("Args = {:?}", args);
        }
    };
}

struct MyStruct {}

impl MyStruct {
    build_fn!(test_single_arg, x: i32);
    build_fn!(test_multi_arg, x: i32, y: i32);
}

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let my_struct = MyStruct {};
    
    my_struct.test_single_arg(10);
    my_struct.test_multi_arg(1, 2);

    Ok(())
}
```

Link to the playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d798cc6a744b53af47dd8cf40fc3b115

Comment: This looked promising, but it doesn't currently compile on the playground. Would you mind updating your answer?

Answer (score 4):

Since @ranfdev's answer is not currently compiling, I've fixed & simpified & extended it to support multiple types -- and it now runs in Rust stable:

```
use std::fmt::Write;

macro_rules! build_vararg_fn {
    ($name:tt, $($v:tt: $t:ty),+) => {

        fn $name($($v: $t),+) {
            let mut msg = String::from("args: ");
            $(
                write!(msg, "{:?}, ", $v).unwrap();
            )+
            println!("{}", &msg[..msg.len()-2]);
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    build_vararg_fn!(test_single_arg, x: i32);
    build_vararg_fn!(test_multi_arg, x: i32, y: i32);
    build_vararg_fn!(test_multi_type, x: i32, y: i32, z: f64);

    test_single_arg(10);
    test_multi_arg(1, 2);
    test_multi_type(1, 2, 3.14159);
}
```

Output:

```
args: 10
args: 1, 2
args: 1, 2, 3.14159
```

See it on [Playgroud!](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6107cea7f0f0796655fc255655101ce4)