# "Expected one of `(` or `<`, found `$`" when generating function code with a macro in Rust

Tags: rust, macros, metaprogramming, macro-rules

To avoid writing hundreds of lines of repetitive code - I am trying to use declarative macros (macro_rules!) to generate the struct method code. For some reason though, I am getting a confusing error `Expected one of '(' or '<', found '$'`, where it should have expanded a metavariable, `$x`.

This a snippet of my code:

```
//...

macro_rules! LD_X_Y {
        ($x:ident, $y:ident) => {
            pub fn ld_$x_$y(&mut self, opcode: u8) {
                self.cpu.set_$x(self.cpu.get_$y());
            }
        };
}

impl GB {
    //...

    LD_X_Y!(a, b);

    //...
}
```

The error is indicated at the `$x` in the function name `ld_$x_$y` (line 3). I have been using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70872059/using-a-rust-macro-to-generate-a-function-with-variable-parameters) as well as [The Rust Reference section on macros](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/macros.html) as reference.

Does anyone know why this doesn't work? Thank you.